# how to get selected week days dates between Start date and end date with 14 day recurrence pattern using Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, dayofweek, days

I need to return some date object which occurs between Start Date and End Date with recurrence pattern and given weekdays using pure javaScript(No postman or moment). I am able to get date object for 1 week. But I am not able to get the date object for more than a week(14 or 21 days).
Here is my below code.

```
 function dates{
            var startDate = new Date("2020/06/22"); 
            var endDate = new Date("2020/08/16");
            var recurrencePattern = 14 ;// 2 weeks
            var daysSelected = [0,1]; //0 - sunday , 1 - monday
            var datesObj = [];
            while(startDate <= endDate){
            var i=0;
            while(i<daysSelected.length){
                if(startDate.getDay() ==  daysSelected[i]){
                   datesObj.push(startDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(startDate.getMonth()+01)+"-"+startDate.getDate());
                }
                i++;
            }
                startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() +1);
            }
            return datesObj;
          }
```

the output I should get (every 2 weeks, selected Sunday and Monday fall between 22/06/2020 and 16/08/2020) is

```
datesObj["22-06-2020","5-07-2020","6-07-2020","19-07-2020","20-07-2020","2-08-2020","3-08-2020","16-08-2020"]
```

but I am getting all the Sunday and Monday dates to fall from the start and end date. Can anyone please fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `while(i<daysSelected.length){ ... }` code with below code.

```
if (daysSelected.includes(startDate.getDay())) {
  datesObj.push(startDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (startDate.getMonth() + 01) + "-" + startDate.getDate());
}
```

Moreover to skip `recurrencePattern = 14` days when you encounter `last day of week` which is `startDate.getDay() == 6` then skip `recurrencePattern-7+1` days. You need to subtract `7` from `recurrencePattern` because you are already processing for `one week` with `loop`. Also use `datesObj.length > 0` so it will only skip `weeks` when `dates` are `actually` added for respective week.

Below is complete code. you can check it.

```js
function dates(startDate, endDate) {
  var recurrencePattern = 14; // 2 weeks
  var daysSelected = [0, 1]; //0 - sunday, 1 - monday
  var datesObj = [];
  while (startDate <= endDate) {

    if (daysSelected.includes(startDate.getDay())) {
      datesObj.push(startDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (startDate.getMonth() + 01) + "-" + startDate.getDate());
    }

    if (datesObj.length > 0 && startDate.getDay() == 6) {
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (recurrencePattern - 7 + 1));
    } else {
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
  return datesObj;
}

console.log(dates(new Date("2020/06/22"), new Date("2020/08/16")));
```

**Update** For `var daysSelected = [0, 4];` include all days between `0` to `4`.

```js
function dates(startDate, endDate) {
  var recurrencePattern = 14; // 2 weeks
  var daysSelected = [0, 4]; //0 - sunday to 4 - thursday
  var startDay = Math.min(...daysSelected);
  var endDay = Math.max(...daysSelected);
  var datesObj = [];
  while (startDate <= endDate) {

    if (startDay <= startDate.getDay() && endDay >= startDate.getDay()) {
      datesObj.push(startDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (startDate.getMonth() + 01) + "-" + startDate.getDate());
    }

    if (datesObj.length > 0 && startDate.getDay() == 6) {
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (recurrencePattern - 7 + 1));
    } else {
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
  return datesObj;
}

console.log(dates(new Date("2020/06/22"), new Date("2020/08/16")));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Karan. It is working fine. I am very glad that you solved my problem.

Comment: Lets 22-06-2020 - day is Monday. if we pass other than the current day, I mean DaysSelected = [0,4], with recurrence pattern = 14, I got wrong datesObj, Karan. Can you please help me with that. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is expected output for this? If `DaysSelected = [0,4]` then do you need to include `sunday` & `thursday` or need to also include days between `sunday` & `thursday`?

Comment: Karan, its nothing but, how outlook meeting occurrence (for weekly)is working. It will take only selected days with occurrence and recurrence patterns.  plz refer outlook as a reference and you will get some idea. I have been sitting with this for a couple of weeks. if you could help me, I will be very happy. Thanks in advance.